# streaming openCV frame using h264 encoding

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, h.264

I created a python program using OpenCV and GStreamer to stream the frames to a GStreamer `udpsink`. Here is the code :

```py
import cv2
import config

def send():
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #open the camera
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency noise-reduction=10000 bitrate=2048 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000',fourcc,config.CAP_PROP_FPS, (800,600),True) #ouput GStreamer pipeline

    if not out.isOpened():
        print('VideoWriter not opened')
        exit(0)

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret,frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            

            # Write to pipeline
            out.write(frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    cap_send.release()
    out_send.release()

send()
```

Then, in my terminal, my GStreamer receiver pipeline is :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The problem is that the frames that I receive are like that :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14PeiGlEfcSuzRjSPENrCjGQIQk-04OHb

I guess it's all about color space conversion in openCV... What do you think?

Comment: Is there any reason to disable RGB conversion **cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)** ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I deleted this line but the problem is still here...

Answer (score 1):

with the 640x480 resolution, I can see some improvements but it's still far from being acceptable...
(I put the link of the image here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YBNEKOcC9fK6hS5RatvkO9pjKhcbh6Eu)

But anyway, I found that for a 1280x720 resolution, it is pretty good! Though, my camera is supporting other resolution (like 800x600 or 640x480) but there are not working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Check the Video Resolution your camera is supporting .

Example VGA : 640 x 480

Use the same resolution in your gstreamer pipeline. ( Unless you are doing some rescaling)